# Styling <select> list choices on mobiles

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, mobile

I was wondering if it is possible to style the list box when you tap a drop down (select) on a mobile. I have a feeling it is browser level so I can affect it but maybe I am wrong...

This is the kind of thing I mean...I have a drop down of delivery choices and when tapped this box pops up:

[image: select options]

Comment: What is the code that you used?

Comment: It's a standard <select><option></option></select>

On a mobile when you tap the select instead of a list you get this pop over box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile as on desktop, select options list is not affected by your css, this is handled by the browser itself.

If you want to customize options list, you can use javascript to make an "alias" list (with ul, li) that you can design with css.
There is also libraries in jquery that can make your work easier (ex: https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: I thought so, looks like I will have to look at what is in list text wise to smarten it up.